# VBA CountIfs ignores an argument

Tags: vba, excel

I am having the following trouble with my `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs` code bellow.

When I do the countifs making it look and count for the word "TER", it works.

When I do the countifs between the dates, it works.

When I put the arguments I said together it just count between the dates, it's like the countifs ignored the argument I want to count the word TER in the column.
I researched a lot, and couldn't find something that helps. Already tried put two quotes in ""TER"".

Thank you.

```
Dim TerminPerio As Integer, IniRAM As Date, FimRAM As Date
Dim NecessTOT As Integer

IniRAM = #12/1/2016#           
FimRAM = #12/31/2016#

NecessTOT = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("L:L"), "TER", Range("I:I"), ">=" & CDbl(IniRAM), Range("I:I"), "<=" & CDbl(FimRAM)) 
'NecessTOT = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("L:L"), "TER")
'NecessTOT = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("I:I"), ">=" & CDbl(IniRAM), Range("I:I"), "<=" & CDbl(FimRAM)) 

MsgBox (CStr(NecessTOT))

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean that your solution counts also lines which match in regards of date but not for condition in range `L:L`? I put your code and for me it works fine. Did you replicated the same function in Excel worksheet? If yes the result was correct or the same as in VBA?

Comment: Do all the values that fall between the two dates also have "TER" in column L?  If so, then obviously the answer will be the same as if you just counted how many rows fall between the two dates.  The answer will only be reduced if you have some non-"TER" values in column L.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping, everybody.
My solution for my counts was doing something else:
In a brief, to get the result i wanted, I did some sequential autofilters to the columns, copied the lines affected and counted the number of registers with another command line.

Example:

```
Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$L$1:$L" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=27, Criteria1:=CStr(MESRAM)
    ActiveSheet.Range("$AK$1:$AK" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=28, Criteria1:=CStr(ANORAM)
    ActiveSheet.Range("$AE$1:$AE" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=29, Criteria1:=CStr(MESRAM)

LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```